# Why are the cross validation results for my classifier so different?

Tags: python, machine-learning, cross-validation

I am making a predictive model in python with scikit-learn, and I am trying to cross validate to get a valid F1 score. However, depending on my CV method, I am getting very different results. It seems that issues like this are typically due to overfitting or bad data, but in this case that shouldn't explain how my methods give consistent internal results even with different splits, but always differ from each other. `x` is my dataset, `y` is the labels, and `rf_best` is my classifier. For example:

```
cv_scores = cross_val_score(rf_best, x, y, cv=5, scoring='f1')
avg_cv_score = np.mean(cv_scores)

print cv_scores
avg_cv_score
```

returns

```
Out[227]:
[ 0.39825853  0.55969686  0.58727599  0.64060356  0.41976476]
0.52111993918160837
```

while (changing `cv` from 5 splits to a `ShuffleSplit` function)

```
cv = ShuffleSplit(len(y), n_iter=5, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)

cv_scores = cross_val_score(rf_best, x, y, cv=cv, scoring='f1')
avg_cv_score = np.mean(cv_scores)

print cv_scores
avg_cv_score
```

returns

```
Out[228]:
[ 0.88029259  0.86664242  0.8898564   0.87900669  0.86130213]

0.87542004725953615
```

I'm sure the classifier isn't performing this well, and I don't see how I could be overfitting with 5 shufflesplits, especially as I rerun it over and over. And this:

```
scores = []
for train, test in KFold(len(y), n_folds=5): #.25 tt split
    xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = x[train], x[test], y[train], y[test]

    rf_best.fit(xtrain, ytrain)    
    scores.append(f1_score(ytest, rf_best.predict(xtest)))

print scores
np.mean(scores)
```

returns

```
Out[224]:
[0.3365789517232205, 0.39921963139526107, 0.47179614359341149, .56085913206027882, 0.3765470091576244]

0.42900017358595932
```

How can 3 methods which are doing close to the same thing return such different results so consistently? Even when I change the random seed or test-set size, the results stay similar to what I posted above. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here the `ShuffleSplit` set is performing much better than the other splitting methods, so the issue should not be that unshuffled data is retaining information.

Comment: It (correlations due to no shuffling) may be the case. If your classifier learned to use such correlations, then it'll fail to use them on the held-out (test) set.

Comment: Could you help me understand how to alter the code to avoid this? Just shuffle the order of samples in x before the train/test split?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use `sklearn` to [shuffle](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.shuffle.html) the dataset right after loading.

Comment: Ok so changing `shuffle=True` on Kfold leads to a much higher score, similar to shuffle split. I see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#a-note-on-shuffling) that shuffling contiguous data can lead to overfitting. How does this work? The data order is not arbitrary, so according to the link I need to shuffle if the data is contiguous (and it is). However this is leading to an artificially high score, why is that?

Comment: What's the data you're working with? If the data have time component (or equivalent), then the later observations are likely to be influenced by the former ones.